# Need a reference/proof for computing the regularity of ideal of points in $\mathbb P^d$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra

In a lecture notes on 'Cohomology modules' i read the following remark:

> Given a set $X$ of points in $\mathbb P^d$,using the Local Cohomology modules one can easily compute the reg$(S_X)$ where $S_X=\frac {S}{I_X}$,and $I_X$ is the homogeneous ideal of $X$.

Could anyone please explain(/give reference) me that how do we find reg$(S_X)$ in the mentioned case?

Note: The above question was first asked on MSE but unfortunately i din't get any answer there.

Comment: I guess it depends on what "compute" means. Does something like Corollary 4.7 in Eisenbud's book on syzygies help?

Comment: Dear @Hoot: of course it is helpful,please let me know if you have any other reference related with this?Thanks!